Prove that if $Av=μv$, then $A^2v=μ^2v$
Given two n x n invertible matrices A and B, two nonzero constants μ and ν, and a nonzero vector v such that
                        Av = μv
                        Bv = νv

Find an eigenvalue and corresponding eigenvector of the matrix A^2 + B^2
I know how to solve it once its in the form
                        A^2v = μ^2v
                        B^2v = ν^2v

(add the two equations and the eigenvalue just becomes (μ^2 + ν^2) and the eigenvector is v),
but I'm not sure how to get from the first two equations to the second two equations.

What happens when you apply $A$ to both sides of $A v = \mu v$?

Duh! Thank you. Seems like the easiest step, guess I was overthinking.

It's a good idea to check what happens if you apply $A^2 + B^2$ to $v$. You get:
\begin{align}
(A^2 + B^2)v &= A^2(v) + B^2(v)\\
 &= A(Av) + B(Bv)\\
 &= A(\mu v) + B(\nu v)\\
 &= \mu A(v) + \nu B(v)\\
 &= \mu (\mu v) + \nu (\nu v)\\
 &= \mu^2 v + \nu^2 v\\
 &= (\mu^2 + \nu^2) v.
\end{align}
Therefore, we can conclude that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^2 + B^2$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\mu^2 + \nu^2$.

Ah nice, I can see some things don't change. Like getting down votes without context...
